# Alternate to "if" to do different things in a function depending on arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to change the behavior of a function depending on the argument that is being passed in. I am thinking of using an if statement but i really don't want to.
Example:

```
def BigPrime(numP, plist = [], x = 1, counter =0):
    while len(plist) <= numP:
            if x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 5:
                    plist.append(x)
            elif x % 2 is not 0 and int(str(x)[-1]) is not 5:
                    for div in plist[1:]:
                                    #Non mettere niente qui, strane magie
                                    #accadono in questo luogo...
                            if x % div == 0:
                                    break
                    else:
                            plist.append(x)
                    counter += 1
            x += 1
    return plist, counter
```

Edit: OK since this example did not convice many i put the real function. Sorry for the confusion! Any suggestion is welcome!

i'd need something like this:

```
def foo(arg = 0, x = 0):
    if not arg:
        while True:
            pass
    else:
        while x < arg:
            print('bar')
            x+=1
```

This really looks awful,
is this really the only way? Isn't there a more elegant work around?

Comment: That's exactly what it should look like, i put there a 'pass' because the whole code is too long to write down and it's not irrilevant... The thing i did like to know was if there was some strange method or 'magic' that could do the trick instead of an if statement. :)

Comment: `foo` and `arg` are hardly what it "should" look like :) Anyway, `if/else` as such is fairly idiomatic in Python, even as a top-level condition, because *Python doesn't have native support for pattern-matching or function guards*. I would probably use separate functions to do the actual work, perhaps even nested functions. Of course code can get as crazy as .. desired.

Comment: Edited, now there's the real function! :D

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Didn't know of that. Next time i will, sorry for spamming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the behavior of your function `foo` is completely unrelated in the two cases, I don't think there's anything really wrong with the `if`.

Since you're determined to avoid the `if` statement you could define two functions and select between them any other way you choose:

```
def foo(arg = 0, x = 0):
    def loop_forever():
        while True:
            pass
    def print_stuff():
        while x < 100:
            print('bar')
            x += 1
    # now, any of these:

    # if expression not if statement!
    print_stuff() if arg else loop_forever() 

    # what people did before the if expression
    # *but* you have to change print_stuff to return a true value
    arg and print_stuff() or loop_forever()

    # data-driven design, buzzword-compliant ;-)
    [loop_forever, print_stuff][bool(arg)]()
```

Generally to choose a technique for this you'd look at what is the same and what is different between the two cases, and decide what abstractions to use on that basis. But in this case there's nothing the same between the two.

There's a kind of "ugly in, ugly out" principle at work here: there is basically no way to express two unrelated operations other than by writing them separately in two different places. Whether you separate those places as the clauses of an `if`, or as two different functions, or as two different classes with polymorphism, is pretty much irrelevant if there is only one point in your code that is responsible for defining them, selecting between them, and executing one. If those three things were done in different places then you'd have significant decisions to make.

For your real code, here's what I think I'd write, for what that's worth. It's entirely possible I've introduced a bug, but I don't think it's so much code that I'd be looking to write more functions. I don't claim to understand the purpose of the code because, like, 3 is prime, but I believe the following is equivalent:

```
def BigPrime(numP, plist = [], x = 1, counter =0):
    while len(plist) <= numP:
        if x in (1, 2, 5):
            plist.append(x)
        elif x % 2 != 0 and x % 5 != 0
            if all(x % div != 0 for div in plist[1:]):
                plist.append(x)
            counter += 1
        x += 1
    return plist, counter
```

There's a possible optimization, that `plist[1:]` copies the array and so `itertools.islice(plist, 1, None)` might be better.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer.
I feared i was trying to do too much with only one function.
Those expressions you wrote there will be very very helpful! i learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: I didn't know of that all() expression, more documentations then. Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, needing this feature indicates a possibly bad design. Usually, a function shall achieve one single clear goal. If two distinct behaviours are needed, it should be implemented as too different functions.

```
def block_script():
    while True:
        pass

def wait_and_spam(x = 0):
    while x < 100:
        print('bar')
        x+=1
```

A function can achieve the same goal with different sets of parameters. In this case one can most often first inspect the arguments to fill the missing ones with default values, prepare the data according to the parameters and then run the same algorithm. There is one special case for statically typed languages where the implementation of the algorithm itself have to be changed according to the type of arguments, and overloading is then a nice feature. But it's not the case of Python.

```cpp
/* Add two values with protection against overflow (short) */
unsigned short secure_add(unsigned short a, unsigned short b) {
    unsigned long result = (unsigned long)a + (unsigned long)b;
    if (result > (unsigned long)0xFFFF) {
        return (unsigned short)0xFFFF;
    } else {
        return (unsigned short) result;
    }
}

/* Add two values with protection against overflow (char) */
unsigned char secure_add(unsigned char a, unsigned char b) {
    unsigned short result = (unsigned short)a + (unsigned short)b;
    if (result > (unsigned short)0xFF) {
        return (unsigned char)0xFF;
    } else {
        return (unsigned char) result;
    }
}
```

Finally, Python provides functionalities like `getattr` that allows to get a reference to a function based on its name. The name can be constructed at runtime.

```
class Parser:

    def parse(self, source, initpos = 0):
        for token in self.lexer.get_tokens(source, initpos):
              # Call the state handler
              statemgr = getattr(self, "_s_"+self.state)
              statemgr(token)

    def _s_func_header(self, token):
        if token.name == "parenthesis_open":
            self.state = "function_arguments"
        # ...

    def _s_function_arguments(self, token):
        # ...
```

Comment: Yeah, i figured i gave a single function too many goal. Well, i tried ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list or dict of functions:

```
def foo_0(x):
    while True:
        pass

def foo_1(x):
    while x < 100:
        print('bar')
        x += 1

def foo_list(arg=0, x=0):
    [foo_0, foo_1][arg](x)

def foo_dict(arg=0, x=0):
    {0: foo_0, 1: foo_1}[arg](x)
```

If your arg can be outside [0, 1] you need to constrain it before indexing the list or dict.